# Image onload not executing properly?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm trying to set up a resize function to my images' onloads so that if the image is larger than the user's browser window, it resizes itself. When I put a function like:

```
function resize(){
    console.log(this.width);
}
```

It says 0 or NaN or undefined. If I run the function on the images later, I get the correct results... How can I set an onload that will be able to access the height and width attributes?

edit: Sorry for the confusion: http://jsfiddle.net/9aDFe/

The images are the ones found on google under the search "landscape"

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?  It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/EtzHT/

Comment: Your jsFiddle does not show the error your describe

Comment: @Chris, that's really weird. It doesn't happen when I load the page, but it does when I hit run on jsfiddle. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I don't get it when I run it, either.

Comment: @Chris, in Chrome, when I hit run, the values in the console are all NaN except the last two.... This is pretty weird...

Comment: The only errors I'm getting in chrome is from: `GET http://www.kidsgeo.com/images/landscape.jpg 403 (Forbidden)` All of the other loop iterations are printing numbers to the console http://i.imgur.com/LjkAo.png

Comment: I see no issues in any browser.  As long as you set the `onload` handler before setting `.src`, onload should get called reliably when the image loads successfully and height and width should be valid.  I've been using it that way for years.  If the images are cached, some browsers will fire onload immediately when you set .src so you will not get an onload if it is set after .src (and the images are in the browser cache).  But, the way you're doing it looks right and works for me in all four browsers I tried on first load and subsequent hits of the Run button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cross browser solution is to use a combination of readystatechange and load

```
var image = new Image();
image.addEventListener ("readystatechange", yourImageOnloadChecker);
image.addEventListener ("load", yourImageOnloadChecker);
image.src = "path/to/your/image"; // set SRC after your events. it's an IE fix
```

Your image onload checker function should check for isNaN or equal to 0 on the height/width and if so, set up a callback to itself with setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** *This answer was made invalid by details added to the question after I answered. I'll leave this here for reference (since this does address a valid and likely-to-occur problem), but note that this is not the solution to the specific issue the OP describes.*

If you are using a library that gives a "domReady" event (or even, in some situations, if your script is at the bottom of the page), then your onload function isn't being attached to the image in time - it has already loaded. Especially if you're using the `body.onload` event - this isn't fired until the image is completely loaded.

If you'd like to work with an image in this fashion (via code executed at `body.onload`), then you can just directly access the image - it is already loaded. Subsequent images dynamically placed on the page will fire the onload event as you expect, since they were added after the fact.

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload for more discussion on the event, and suggested alternatives that fire at different times in the loading process.

Comment: But apparantly it does run - "It says 0 or NaN or undefined". How would it log to the console if it doesn't run?  I don't think that's the issue.  (not my downvote, btw)

Comment: Aye. The jsFiddle the OP added doesn't show the error for me, either.